# svn URL access forbidden for unknown reason

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, checkin

I'm trying to create a new project in svn using subclipse from STS/Eclipse. It works fine with existing projects, this is just a project for experimentation. When I try to check in the new project, I get this error message

```
mkdir --parents -m "Initial import." https://utilities.mycompany.com/svn/repo/springMvcTest
    URL access forbidden for unknown reason
svn: access to '/svn/repo/!svn/ver/10618/' forbidden

    Filesystem has no item
svn: URL 'https://utilities.mycompany.com/svn/repo/test' non-existent in that revision
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It would seemingly be a problem on the server.  I can only guess based on the info available but it is possible the server Apache process that the Subversion server runs in does not have write access to the repository location on the native filesystem of the server.